# How can I declare a float-typed Go constant of arbitrary bit pattern?

Tags: go, floating-point, bit-manipulation, constants

In Go I can declare a typed float constant like this:

```
const foo float64 = 1e100
```

or a float variable of arbitrary bit pattern like this:

```
var bar = math.Float64frombits(0x7ff8c0c0ac0ffee1)
```

But this is an error ("const initializer… is not a constant"):

```
const baz = math.Float64frombits(0x7ff8c0c0ac0ffee1)
```

How might I declare a typed float const of arbitrary bit pattern?

Comment: You can store it as a `uint64` constant and convert it on demand (which is how the math package does it internally)

Comment: That's actually a good suggestion.  It's a bit annoying for exported values (e.g. ones used as sentinel values) because the dependant package would also need to import `math`, but at least it ensures constness.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store the bit value (which is essentially a `uint64`), and have it available as a `float64` to external packages, you can provide a "constant" function, which you guarantee to only return the constant value. This is precisely how functions like [`math.NaN`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#NaN) work.

```
const uintFoo = 0x7ff8c0c0ac0ffee1

func ConstFoo() float64 {
    return math.Float64frombits(uintFoo)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to Math.Float64frombits occurs at runtime, not compile time, and thus, is not constant. From the effective Go page (which will explain it better than I can):

> Constants in Go are just that—constant. They are created at compile
>   time, even when defined as locals in functions, and can only be
>   numbers, strings or booleans. Because of the compile-time restriction,
>   the expressions that define them must be constant expressions,
>   evaluatable by the compiler. For instance, 1<<3 is a constant
>   expression, while math.Sin(math.Pi/4) is not because the function call
>   to math.Sin needs to happen at run time.

Link: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants

Comment: I understand that.  But it does not answer the question.  (I think the answer to the question might be "submit a go language change proposal", but I want to make sure I have not missed something before I do that.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a function like `Float64frombits` in a constant declaration; the function call means it can't be evaluated fully at compile time, so it can't be used as a constant. You can, however, just dump bits into a float value:

```
const myFloat float64 = 0x7ff8c0c0ac0ffee1

func main() {
    fmt.Println(myFloat)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't apply the bitwise representation to the float64, it's essentially `float64(0x7ff8c0c0ac0ffee1)`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Question wasn't specific on the details of what they were expecting as output from the input, so I gave the only available option for setting a const value from an arbitrary hex value.

Comment: The question specifies results equivalent to `Float64frombits`. Numerically converting an arbitrary hex value to a float64 is not the same as interpreting the uint64 bits as a float64.

Comment: Depending on the value, it could be made equivalent using an appropriate hex value. It's hard to say, since the question's example `math.Float64frombits(0x7ff8c0c0ac0ffee1)` returns `NaN`.

Comment: That's part of the point, the bits start with the NaN mask value, and can't by written as a float64 literal. Not to mention that since hex literals can only be integral values, they represent a very small portion of possible float64 values, so it can only be approximated in a very limited sense.